# Code Metrics Analysis for Unmanaged C++ Code

Tags: c++, mfc, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

Does anyone know of a free tool, similar to what is built into Visual Studio 2010 for managed code, that can do analysis of unmanaged, MFC C++ code and give metrics (lines of code, dependency or coupling, etc)?

I've been searching on Google for awhile, but really haven't been able to find anything that works. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) is a good free tool tool for code metrics such as LoC and complexity and also produces kiviat graphs. But it does not have any depedency or coupling metrics.

Comment: Thanks! Not perfect, but this was what I ended up using. It got the job done on at least a basic level while also being easy to setup and use without a lot of overhead (unlock some of the other programs). It's not the most intuitive, but as I worked with it, I found a lot more data than was immediately shown by digging around. Nice tool overall!

Answer (score 3):

Our [SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/) tool can analyze your Visual C++ project and provide you all the information you asked for: metrics (lines of code, dependency, coupling, 60+ metrics altogether). The results are in standard CSV files, which you can easily open in e.g. spreadsheet editors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about free tool but one paid tool which is most comprehensive is IBM's Logiscope http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/logiscope/

Answer (score 0):

Not free but [QA-CPP](http://www.programmingresearch.com/qacpp_main.html) does metrics like cyclomatic complexity and static analysis.

It's fairly complex to set up but they are pretty good on product support and regularly put out updates.